# Creating a Combobox from a Class  - In VB.net

Tags: vb.net

im new to vb.net, and my query is:

**file:** read.vb

```
 Friend Function Nav()
    Dim NavBox As New ComboBox()
    NavBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(44, 21)
    NavBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(135, 305)
    NavBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    NavBox.Items.Add("1")
    NavBox.Items.Add("2")
    NavBox.Items.Add("3")
    NavBox.Items.Add("4")
    NavBox.Items.Add("5")
    NavBox.Items.Add("6")
    NavBox.Items.Add("7")
    NavBox.Items.Add("8")
    NavBox.Items.Add("9")
    NavBox.Items.Add("10")
    NavBox.Items.Add("11")
    AddHandler (NavBox.SelectionChangeCommitted), AddressOf MSGB
    NavBox.Show()
    Return NavBox
End Function
Public Sub MSGB(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim cb As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    MsgBox(cb.SelectedItem)

End Sub
```

And im calling this function or displaying this combobox in mainFrom.vb

**file:** mainFrom.vb

```
    Dim l As New read
    Me.Controls.Add(CType(l.Nav(), Control))
```

Now what i need is, a access to its control so i can parss value from **mainFrom.vb** to **read.vb** to manipulation the SelectionChangeCommitted activity.

I hope my question is clear....

Comment: Do you have a porpuose in doing all this in code?? and not just using the interface on VS?

Comment: Yes i do have a purpose writing all this code...
basically i have  11 Form Windows for which i need to give a comboBox based navigation by implementing the code instead of creating each one in single form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you control is a simple ComboBox, I don't see the point of having common code to create this control. You can have a common function to populate it's contents though.

If you want to add functionality to the ComboBox, just create your own combo box class, let's say ExtendedComboBox, which inherits from ComboBox, and use it in your forms.

If you don't want to change your existing code, you can assign your ComboBox returned from Nav to a variable, and then hook into events from this ComboBox:

```
Public Class MainForm

'Declare NavBox as a form member
Private NavBox As ComboBox

Public Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Create NavBox
    Dim read As New read
    NavBox = read.Nav()

    'Hook NavBox event so MainForm knows when selection is changed
    AddHandler NavBox.SelectionChangeCommitted, AddressOf NavBox_SelectionChangedCommited

    'Add NavBox to MainForm
    Me.Controls.Add(NavBox)
End Sub

Public Sub NavBox_SelectionChangedCommited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim cb As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    'Do something when selection changes.
End Sub

End Class
```

You should also remove the useless AddHandler line inside the Nav function.

Comment: Ops Sorry its my mistake...
This piece is actually a part of my idiotic trial and error tryout... `NavBox.Controls.Add(NavBox)`..

Comment: OK, removed that last part. First part still holds true, I don't think you should have such a "read" class.

Comment: can atleast know how to give a custom control to this piece of code..
`Me.Controls.Add(CType(l.Nav(), Control))` 
Coz the rest is working perfectly...
Just need to know how to give a custom control to the above line or object which is being accessed from a external class file. Called read.vb i hope this makes sense...

Comment: Look at my edit. Your question is not entirely clear but I showed how I would use your code.

Comment: Thanks a ton...
And yes that's why you are in an expert level ;) ...
.
.
.
My logic is completely a mess i know :P..
Thanks once again...